# Рукопожатие (шифрование) общения клиента и сервера на php

Tags: php, c#, websocket, клиент-сервер

Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой, как реализация защиты связи между своим приложением и сервером от перехвата (MItM, например). Думаю реализовывать что-то вроде [протокола Диффи-Хеллмана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Но тут возникает вопрос, как именно это сделать, ведь сервер у меня планировался на php, а приложение уже написано на C#.

Как я вижу процесс?
1) Клиент отправляет запрос
2) Сервер отправляет ответ на него
3) Клиент этот ответ принимает, и они с сервером вычисляют ключ. Клиент отправляет уже основной запрос
4) Сервер работает с DB и даёт ответ.
И всё это в одном подключении.

Как я понял, для этого мог бы подойти WebSocket сервер, но там много проблем, и он не работает так, как мне надо. Например, он должен быть постоянно запущен, и некоторые пишут, что это общий сервер для всех клиентов.

Надеюсь на помощь, так как не могу понять, что мне делать в данной ситуации.

Comment: Какой смысл в собственной реализации шифрования, чем не подходит ssl (https) ? И почему собственно WebSocket мог бы подойти, требуется постоянно установленное соединение и есть требование, что бы оно было поверх http ?

Comment: и ещё, всёж пых или шарп?

Comment: @qwabra написано же, клиент на шарпе, сервер на пхп

Comment: @Mike HTTPS можно перехватить, используя тот же Fiddler. Поэтому я хочу сделать такого рода шифрование. Чтобы даже при перехвате приложение всё равно было защищено, ведь трафик зашифрован. А WebSocket... Ну, тут я представляю telnet. Он работает примерно также. Несколько запросов в одном соединении, для каждого клиента соединения разные.

Comment: https невозможно перехватить в случае если приложение явно проверяет сертификат сервера, не доверяя проверку системным библиотекам (которым можно подложить собственный доверенный сертификат). Дополнительно полезно использовать клиентский сертификат со стороны приложения, наличие которого так же проверяет сервер. Хотя конечно перехватить то можно, но для этого потребуется декомпиляция приложения, подстановка в него других сертификатов (проверяемого серверного и вытаскивание клиентского), но декомпиляция позволит разобраться и с любым собственным шифрованием

Comment: и конечно надо иметь ввиду, что при большом желании вне зависимости от любых шифрований увидеть трафик можно, повесив хуки на само приложение в точке вызова модулей шифрования

Comment: @Mike Полезная информация, спасибо! От этого само приложение защищать ещё предстоит... Такой вопрос я, возможно, ещё задам. Но всё же, если использовать технологию, описанную выше? Есть какой-то способ? Если нет, то что я могу использовать?

Comment: почитайте немного теории по ssl (https). там собственно все предусмотрено. Ведь главное не шифрование как таковое, а уверенность в том, что тот с кем вы говорите именно тот за кого себя выдает. для этого и используются сертификаты. по умолчанию то что сертификаты не абы какие проверяют библиотеки ssl по корневым сертификатам, установленным в системе. Для перехвата трафика в систему ставят корневой сертификат, которым делает подпись прокси. Если самому проверить сертификат сервера, то никакая прокся уже mitm не сделает, так как не сможет правильно подписать соединение

Comment: А ручная реализация всего это дела обычно неблагодарный труд. Тем более на php. Тем более в таком виде как вы его собрались использовать. Вы же его в обычном режиме, когда его вызывает web сервер ходите использовать, а значит на момент запуска соединение уже установлено и по хорошему уже пришли все данные запроса. Шифрование на этом этапе потребует так же собственного разбора запроса после расшифровки (т.е. выполнить ту работу, которую за вас делает сам php), потом вы не сможете делать вывод php скриптом обычным образом, потому что надо будет весь ответ опять шифровать